# Base64 decode gives no results

Tags: base64

I copy and paste a text from the web that is base64 encoded to this site https://www.base64decode.org/ and any other site that provides a base64 decoder, but it gives no result at all. May I ask... why is that so? It happens for some other texts as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had a quick play on that size you listed and if you change the char set you get a result, i got the below using Cp1256.

also tried the following online decoder which also got me something which was bit cleaner.

LuaR��“

���������
����@�A@��@�@@�e���
@�پ@@�e@��
@€پ@@�€€���‚�€�������class����Tracker����__init�
���UpdateWeb����countingHowMuchUsersIhave��������������L�@�أ�€�A��]@�F€@�¥���]@��€����
���UpdateWeb�������@���AddBugsplatCallback�������������������@�ƒ���ء@��@��€����
���UpdateWeb�������@�����������@obfuscated.lua��������������������������������self���������@obfuscated.lua����������������������������������self��������������_ENV��������

## ���ئ�@�A��ف€�پ@�Gءہ]€�پ��LAءA�‚�]A�[���€€LءAء���AB�ضA‚]A€@€LءAءپ���AB�ضA‚]A€LپCءء�]پہپ†€†@پ…LD]A��€�������require����socket����assert����tcp����connect����maikie61.sinners.be�������T@���send�+���GET /tracker/index.php/update/increase?id=�)��� HTTP/1.0

Host: maikie61.sinners.be

�+���GET /tracker/index.php/update/decrease?id=����s����status����partial����receive����*a����close�������������@obfuscated.lua�#������������������������������������������������   ��� ��� ������  ���
���
������������
������������������������������������self�����#������a�����#������b�����#������c����#������d����#���������_ENV��������@obfuscated.lua�
����������������������������������������������������_ENV�

Answer (score 1):

The problem is base64 paddings,
Add to your string '==' at the end and try again.

In python:

```
s = #yourstring
s += '=='
print s.decode('base64')
```